# Правильный ли запроc, чтобы получить accessToken от Twitter(OAuth2) Swift2.2?

Tags: swift, oauth2, twitter-api

Отправляю следующий запрос:

> в действительности в значения consumerKey и consumerSecret я передаю
>   данные из моего dev.twitter.com аккаунта

```
            let consumerKey = "myConsumerKey"
            let consumerSecret = "myConsumerSecret"
            let credentialsString = "\(consumerKey):\(consumerSecret)"
            let credentialsData = (credentialsString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let base64String = credentialsData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64String)"]
            let params: [String : AnyObject] = ["grant_type": "client_credentials"]


            Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token", headers: headers, parameters: params)
                            .responseJSON { response in switch response.result {
                            case .Success(let JSON):
            //                    print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

                                let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
                                let userModel = response

                                print("----------------")
                                print("")
                                print("userModel from TW")
                                print(userModel)
                                print("")
                                print("----------------")

                                //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                //})

                            case .Failure(let error):
                                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

                                }
                        }
```

В ответ получаю:

```
{
    errors =     (
                {
            code = 99;
            label = "authenticity_token_error";
            message = "Unable to verify your credentials";
        }
    );
}
```

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: а почему .POST?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth2/token